# Iterating over the DOM with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to iterate over a list of DIVs to check if they have **children** and if so, add the **ID** of that DIV to an array along with the **class of the child**. It's ment to save the buildings for a game, if there's a better way to achieve this I'm open to suggestions.

## HTML

```
<div id="grid" class="grid">
    <div id="t1" class="tile"></div>
    <div id="t2" class="tile">
        <img class="Extractor" title="Extractor" src="images/buildings/Extractor.png">
    </div>
    <div id="t3" class="tile"></div>
    <div id="t4" class="tile"></div>
    <div id="t5" class="tile active"></div>
</div>
```

## JS

```
function saveGame() {
// Format like: "[['t2','Extractor']['t8','Forge']]"
  saveData.buildings = $('.tile').children().stuff(?);

  localStorage.saveData = JSON.stringify(saveData);
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94w8b/)

Comment: `.stuff(?)` didn't work for you?

Comment: That's the part were I got stuck

Comment: Did you actually try? Get the id of the elements and their parent, and push them into an Array. Or just use map:  `$('.tile').children("img").map(function(i, el) { return [[el.parentNode.id, el.className]]; }).toArray();` http://jsfiddle.net/94w8b/1/

Comment: @CrazyTrain Thanks! That works like a charm, can you post it as answer, maybe explain how the map function works?

Comment: Sure thing. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.map()` method is used to build a new Array. Here we're selecting the child images, and using map against that collection.

The return values from the `.map()` callback becomes the members of the new Array. Because jQuery's `.map()` is... odd... we need to double up the returned Array because any outer Array gets flattened into the resulting Array.

```
$('.tile').children("img").map(function(i, el) { 
    return [[el.parentNode.id, el.className]]; 
}).toArray();
```

---

The reason for the `.toArray()` at the end is that this version  of `.map()` in jQuery actually returns a jQuery object, which is Array-like, but not an actual Array. So we need to convert it.

Comment: Yeap knew there was a better algorithm than mine :)

Comment: @PatrickEvans: Yours was good too. I gave you a +1 since it did actually solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

use `.each` to loop over each tile, and then `.each` on the children to loop over those, there might be a quicker algorithm someone maybe someone will comment if there is.

```
saveData.buildings = "[['t2','Extractor']['t8','Forge']]"; 
$('.tile').each(function(){
   var parent = $(this); 
   parent.children().each(function(){
      saveData.buildings.push([parent.id,$(this).attr("class")]); 
   });
});
saveData.resources = 'resources';
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but something with this logic should work fine:

```
results = [];

// iterate over every element with class 'tile'
$('.tile').each(function() {

  var $$ = $(this);

  // does this instance of class tile have a child?
  if ($$.children().length > 0) {

     // store data
     var parent = $$.attr('id');
     var child  = $$.children().first().attr('class');
     results.append([parent, child]);

  }
});
```

Comment: Strange how everyone is downvoted but you, I hope you're not downvoting competing answers.

Comment: @mattytommo, I'm not. I just posted this. :)